# Returning arrays from methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

How does one return an array from a Ruby method?

Example:

```
def array(a,b,c)
  WHAT DO I TYPE NOW TO RETURN ["a","b","c"]
end
```

P.S: I am new to this so I apologize in advance in anything in my question seems stupid to anyone.

Comment: Do you really mean you want to return an array after a method is **defined**? If you do, then it is trivial. Just write an array after the definition. Or, did you actually mean you wan to return an array when the method is **executed**?

Comment: when the method if executed

Comment: @ConstantLearning, sorry, they are downvoting you because you didn't make yourself clear. The dudes here can be strict at times.

Comment: @ConstantLearning, you be more polite and upvote all the answers you have received, and choose the best one to accept.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Sadly, vote up requires 15 points of reputation. Otherwise, I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return arity can get important at times, your question was well justified. In Ruby, method return arity is formally always 1, that is, only 1 object is returned. But we can *de facto* achieve higher arity by returning a collection type. You can do it like this:

```
def hello
  [ "hello", "world" ]
end
```

Returning arrays has also special syntactic support:

```
def hello2
  return "hello", "world"
end
```

Try it and see that it works:

```
hello #=> [ "hello", "world" ]
hello2 #=> [ "hello", "world" ]
a, b = hello
a #=> "hello"
b #=> "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you return anything else. If you want a method that returns the number 1, you'd write:

```
def one
  1
end
```

Here, instead of the number 1, you want to return an array. But there is nothing special about arrays — just like you put the number 1 as the last expression in the method, you put an array there.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that:

Answer (score 0):

> The value of the last expression is the default return value of a method in ruby.

I don't know why you want to return an array, but you can make it like this.

```
def test
    ["a", "b", "c"]
end

2.1.2 :070 > test
=> ["a", "b", "c"]

def test(a, b, c)
    [a, b, c]
end

2.1.2 :076 > test("a", "b", "c")
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
```